# can derivative operators be used as individual quantities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can we write $$ {dy\over dx} = \left({1\over dx/dy}\right) $$ 
in every case?

{neglect the case when $dy/dx$ is zero or infinite}

P.S I am a newbie in this forum. Sorry for any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $y=f(x)$, ($y$ as a function of $x$),Then $1 = \frac{dy}{dy} = \frac{df(x)}{dy}$ apply the chain rule $1= \frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy} $

Comment: I agree to what you are saying. If we look at  $ dy / dx $ as a function rather than individual quantities then it means we need to have y as a function of x. It does not mean that x can exist as a function of y. If x cannot exist as a function of y then how  $ dx/dy $ possible to compute?

Answer (score 0):

It should be intuitively reasonable that
$$\dots =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{(x+h)-h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{(x+h)-h}{y(x+h)-y(x)}}=\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}1}{\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)-x}{y(x+h)-y(x)}}=\dots$$

For a more formal approach, and neglecting the case that $dy/dx$ is zero or infinity, note that if for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$, then for every $\delta$ there exists an $\epsilon$, yadyadayada.....